# How can I diagnose this problem: Can't flash ROM to my Samsung Fascinate

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, custom-roms, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-fascinate

When I boot into recovery all the text moves so fast I can't read what's happening, then it just boots normally without the new ROM.  Is there any log I can review to find out what is happening?

Here's a little background on what I'm doing:

I started with a stock Samsung Fascinate fresh from a factory reset.  I rooted it using [this method](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/samsung-fascinate-development/79811-newbie-guide-rooting-fascinate.html).  I installed ROM Manager from the Market then I installed Clockworkmod with [this method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=788099).  Finally I tried to install jt1134's Super Clearn 0.9 (DJ05) from ROM Manager.  It downloads the ROM offers me the option to backup my current ROM (which I decline because it's already backed up) and the option to wipe cache and data which I choose then hit OK.  From here it boots into Recovery and then the text scrolls up the screen so fast I can't see whats happening, then it boots into the regular stock ROM which would suggest the ROM installation failed.  One other note, ClockworkMod recovery appears to work except when I manually boot into it and choose "reboot" it hangs on the clockworkmod icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds very much like the recovery is borked.  I recommend using [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9088113&postcount=1) to re-flash recovery (or even the entire ROM if you can get ahold of an Odin-flashable version).  [Here's a recent guide from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=960118).

Comment: Perfect. It took a little before I warmed up to Odin but it's a pretty good way to load things onto the phone.  Thanks.

Comment: Great.  Odin has definitely saved me many times.